# Magento 2.2: How can I hide or disable Purchase Order payment method for front-end only?

Tags: magento2

I am looking to remove `Purchase Order` payment method from front-end payment options, it should be available for **Admin only**. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: do you want to hide all the time Or based on any condition ?

Comment: All the time. We take Purchase Order orders over the phone in admin and do not want the option to ever show on frontend.

Comment: Did you try my updated answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom module for that, Which will dynamic remove Payment method from front-end :

Create following files:

> app/code/Mago/Custompayment/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Mago_Custompayment',
__DIR__
);
```

> app/code/Mago/Custompayment/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mago_Custompayment" setup_version="1.0.3">
   </module>
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Custompayment/etc/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="payment_method_is_active">
    <observer name="custom_payment" instance="Mago\Custompayment\Observer\PaymentMethodAvailable" />
</event>
</config>
```

> app/code/Mago/Custompayment/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php

```
<?php
namespace Mago\Custompayment\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class PaymentMethodAvailable implements ObserverInterface
{

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    if($this->isadmin()){
        return;
    }
    // you can replace "purchaseorder" with your required payment method code
    if($observer->getEvent()->getMethodInstance()->getCode()=="purchaseorder"){
        $checkResult = $observer->getEvent()->getResult();
        $checkResult->setData('is_available', false); //this is disabling the payment method at checkout page
    }
}

function isadmin($store = null) {
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $om */
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\State $state */
    $state =  $om->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    return 'adminhtml' === $state->getAreaCode();
}
}
```

Thanks for the great Tutorial at [Webkul](https://webkul.com/blog/disable-payment-method-programmatically-magento2/)

**Edit I**: You need to change the location of `events.xml` from

```
app/code/Mago/Custompayment/etc/frontend/events.xml to app/code/Mago/Custompayment/etc/events.xml.
```

You also need to update code for

```
app/code/Mago/Custompayment/Observer/PaymentMethodAvailable.php
```

**Reason:** `payment_method_is_active` observer not working inside frontend area. We make it globally and check area in observer class, if it is admin it will do nothing.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Pawan! I get the following error: Invalid XML in file /home/public_html/app/code/Mago/Custompayment/etc/frontend/events.xml: Premature end of data in tag config line 2 Line: 5

Is this an error in the events.xml file or related to one of the others?

Comment: Hello @Nick, There is </config> tag is missing in events.xml, I have update in answer, Please try now.

Comment: Thank you, I just tried and no longer get an error, but I still see Purchase Order as a payment method. I have cleared system cache and cleared my local browser's cache as well.

Comment: Hello @Nick, Please see updated answer.

Comment: you need to change place of events.xml and update code of PaymentMethodAvailable.php as per update. if still any issue let me know.

Comment: The updated location of events.xml and addition to PaymentMethodAvailable.php did not work for me unfortunately

Comment: I have tested above code and working fine. I think you have missed something.

Comment: please check your code with file path once again.

Comment: I deleted and started from square one and am still not seeing the module take effect, unfortunately. I have ensured the module is activated in configuration and cleared the cache

Comment: Hello @Nick, I have just again check in fresh installation and its working fine.I think there is other cache/configuration issue there.

Comment: which mode you are using for Magento ?

Comment: I am currently in production mode. Do I need to clear static files and redeploy?

Comment: Of course you need to deploy content

Comment: Have you done ?

Comment: I just tried deleting pub/static/cache folder and renamed pub/static/frontend, deployed static content and cleared cache and it is still not working. Purchase order still shows up as a payment method in frontend checkout

Comment: IT WORKS! I had to run php bin/magento setup:di:compile to see the results on the front end. Thank you so much for your help @Pawan!

Comment: Great, good to know that. You can accept and upvote answer :)

Comment: Seems to be working on 2.3.3 with a quick test. Thank you.

Comment: @Webninja, welcome :)